# Error when using a function as an argument of a function

Tags: c++, function, types

I'm trying to create a program to numerically integrate a function between two limits. I've created a minimal example (where the "integral" is always 1.0) to illustrate an error I get. The code below tries to use a function whose arguments are two doubles and a function from doubles to doubles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
double cons(double a, double b, double c(double d))
{        
    return 1.0;
}
double f(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}
int main()
{
    double x;
    double I = cons(0, 1, f(x));
    std::cout << I << "";
}
```

This results in an error on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/):

> 14:31: error: cannot convert 'double' to 'double (*)(double)' for argument '3' to 'double cons(double, double, double (*)(double))'

Obviously, the difference between doubles and double-valued functions is causing a problem here. How can I get this working?

Comment: Did you try `double I = cons(0, 1, f);` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the function, not call it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
double cons(double a, double b, double c(double d))
{        
    return 1.0;
}
double f(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}
int main()
{
    double x;
    double I = cons(0, 1, f);
    std::cout << I << "";
}
```

Comment: OP seems to want to call f with x. Recommend pointing them in the direction of `std::bind`.

Comment: @user4581301, I'm not sure that's what the OP wants. If the attempt if to calculate the definite integral of the function (as mentioned in the post), x is immaterial. Seems to me like the OP just doesn't understand this aspect of C++ yet.

Comment: Good enough. I'll leave the comment there on the off chance they get interested enough to google.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass a function but the result of a function, a double. Second, you didn't correctly declared a *function pointer* as argument.

If you want to pass a double then declare a double as argument:

```
double cons(double a, double b, double c)
{        
    return 1.0*a*b*c;
}
double f(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}
int main()
{
    double x;
    double I = cons(0, 1, f(x));
    std::cout << I << "";
}
```

If you want to pass a *function* (aka *function pointer* as C++ is not a functional language):

```
double cons(double a, double b, double (*c)(double d))
{        
    return 1.0*c(a);
}
double f(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}
int main()
{
    double x;
    double I = cons(0, 1, f);
    std::cout << I << "";
}
```

Comment: Its immaterial. The declaration decays to a function pointer, the same way `int a[3]` decays to `int *a`

Comment: Right, but explicitly using a function pointer makes it clear that it is not a function that have been passed.

Comment: While it's true that C++ isn't a functional language, it has some elements of FP, and in this particular case `std::function` is a nicer choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in this case is that you are calling the function with:

`double I = cons(0, 1, f(x));`

so you actually give cons the return value of f() instead of the actual function. So you need to write this insteed:

```
double I = cons(0, 1, f);
```

As an alternativ you could also use lambda expressions for your problem. For example something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <functional>
double cons(double a, double b, const std::function<double(double)>& callback)
{        
    // do something 
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    double I = cons(0, 1, [](double x){ return x*x});
    std::cout << I << "";
}
```